# How much do I have to care about phone support?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Coming from web development, I'm used to double-check browser support for everything.

I'm slowly starting to get into app development with react native, and there is one thing I'm unable to find on google:

How are phone/OS-requirements handled in react native?

For example flexbox. Checking out the stylesheet-component from react native, I don't find a word about support on older android/ios-versions:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet

Do I need to worry about components not working on older smartphones (while developing with the newest version of react and react native)?

Comment: Stylesheet properties are translated to native view property by react-native, it should work on all devices. You should be more worry about native module linked in your project (most of time theses modules have a target SDK that ensure compatibility).

Comment: Alright, thank you! That's all I need to know for now.